# Need to keep data from not going to null in a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am getting a object with a List from a 3rd party, so I cannot set the constructor. 
I have two ActionResult one gets the object from the 3rd party, and my other one is used by jquery autocomplete.

I can't figure out a way to set the List and keep it from not going null in the next ActionResult...

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
  public List<T> myList;

  public ActionResult CallToGetThirdPartList(ThirdPartyObject obj)
  {
    list = obj.SpecialList;
    return View(obj); //important 
  }
  public ActionResult Search(ThirdPartyObject obj) //gets called from jquery 
  {
     var results = from m in myListist   //this is null
                   where m.Title.StartsWith(term)  
                   select new { label = m.Summary, m.id };  

            return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each HTTP request, a brand-new instance of your controller is created.  That means that if you initialize `myList` in one request, you will get a brand-new instance of `MyController` for the next request in which `myList` is not initialized.

If you need to store data between requests, use [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session.aspx) (for user-specific data) or [Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.cache.aspx) (for site-wide data such as lookup lists).

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the code little bit.

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
public List<T> myList;

 public ActionResult CallToGetThirdPartList(ThirdPartyObject obj)
 {
   list = obj.SpecialList;
   Session["list"] = list;
   return View(obj); //important 
 }
 public ActionResult Search(ThirdPartyObject obj) //gets called from jquery 
 {
   var listFromSession = Session["list"] as List<T>;
   var results = from m in listFromSession   //this is null
               where m.Title.StartsWith(term)  
               select new { label = m.Summary, m.id };  
        Session["result"]=results ;
        return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)
 }
 }
```

I hope this should help.

regards
Parminder

Comment: thanks! I have decided to use cache(as the list does not change per user), but this example works as well! I wish I could give partial answer

Comment: I have answered what you have asked. Thanks, if you dont want to make my answer as your answer. I am not dying without it.